# How to execute logic after the test manual stop?

Tags: java, junit

I'm writing the integration test that launches multiple servers during it's work. I need to be sure that they will be shut down after the test in any possible case, including manual test stop using IDE. Is there is a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can cover almost every stop/halt scenario by registering a Shutdown Hook:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Gracefully shutting down the application/test");
    }
});
```

However if someone issue a `kill -9`, then not even the shutdownHook will capture, as this signal gets handled by the Operating System that kills/aborts the process without even sending the control to it again.

Answer (score 1):

A good choice is to use a shutdown hook inside a custom JUnit runner, for example as follows:

```
import org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError;

public class MyRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {

    public MyRunner(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
        super(klass);

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread("app-shutdown-hook") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Your code here
                System.out.println("End of test");
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Then, use this runner to run your tests:

```
@RunWith(MyRunner.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("My test");
    }

}
```